# How can I column-break long solutions in the Exam class?

Tags: multicol, exam, columnbreak

I want to be able to automatically break `solution`s when they cross column boundaries in my LaTeX code.

There is a [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89254/305489) that answers my question for pagebreaks, but I specifically want to break long solutions w.r.t. columns.

Here is my minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \begin{solution}
        \lipsum
    \end{solution}
    \begin{solution}
        \lipsum
    \end{solution}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the multicols inside the solution.

Comment: @SimonDispa The issue with that is that I want to have multiple separate solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by multiple separate solutions. Please explain or update your MWE.

Comment: You can use \twocolumn instead, albeit forcing a new page in the process.  It is not easy for solution to break pages at all (sort of like tcolorbox).  Multicols puts the whole page into one column, then breaks the column, which prevents solution from doing it.

Comment: @SimonDispa I updated my MWE. In my specific code, I have several questions each with their own respective solution environment, which is why there are several `solution` blocks.